# How to uncheck disabled radio button ? React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`

```js
import React from 'react'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import './Size.style.scss'

class Size extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.checkboxRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (
            this.props.location.search !== prevProps.location.search &&
            this.checkCategoryChanges(this.props.location.search, prevProps.location.search) &&
            this.checkboxRef.current.checked
        ){
            this.checkboxRef.current.checked = false;
        }
    }

    checkCategoryChanges (currentUrl, prevUrl) {
        let items = currentUrl.charAt(0) === '?' ? currentUrl.slice(1).split('&') : currentUrl.split('&');

        for(const item of items) {
            if(
                (item.indexOf('categories') !== -1 && prevUrl.indexOf(item) === -1) ||
                (item.indexOf('categories') !== -1 && items.length === 1 )
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    isChecked(e) {
        if(this.props.isChecked) {
            if(e.checkboxRef.current && e.checkboxRef.current.checked === false) {
                // e.checkboxRef.current.checked = true;
                this.runOnChange(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        const mainUrlAsArray = window.location.href.split('?');
        if(mainUrlAsArray.length === 2) {
            const url = mainUrlAsArray[1];
            let checkedItems = url.charAt(0) === '?' ? url.slice(1).split('&') : url.split('&');

            for(const item of checkedItems) {
                if(item.indexOf(this.props.urlKey) !== -1 && item.split('=')[1].indexOf(this.props.value) !== -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
   }
   
   runOnChange(e) {
        const checkboxData = {
            value: this.props.value,
            urlKey: this.props.urlKey,
            isChecked: e,
            type: this.props.type ? this.props.type : 'checkbox' 
        }
        this.props.onChange(checkboxData);
   }

    render() {

        return (
            <>
                   <label className="size-label">
                        <input 
                          ref = {this.checkboxRef}
                          defaultChecked={this.isChecked(this) ? true : undefined}
                          value={this.props.value}
                          onChange={(e) => this.runOnChange(e.target.checked)}
                          type={this.props.type ? this.props.type : 'checkbox'}
                          className="size-radio"
                          name="size"
                          disabled={this.props.disabled}
                          />
                        <span className="size-button size-2">{this.props.label}</span>
                    </label>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Size)
```

`I have a radio buttons represent product sizes. I added default checked for the first radio button. And added quantity for product sizes. If product size quantity is 0 I add disabled={true}.But there is a problem, if my first size of product quantity is 0 it is still checked. I want to add default checked for the next radio button if first one is disabled ? But I can not solve this problem. Can anyone please help me ?[image]

```
  {this.state.colorData.map((size,index) => 
                                        <Size
                                            onChange={(e) => this.setState({size: e.value})}
                                            key={index}
                                            type="radio"
                                            value={size.variation}
                                            label={size.variation}
                                            isChecked={index === 0 && this.state.size === ''}
                                            disabled={size.qty ? false : true }
                                        />
                                    )}
```

Comment: It would probably be beneficial if we could see your ```Size``` component.

Comment: @Michael I added